# Get-winEvent to XML, now how to get the values out

Tags: xml, powershell, get-winevent

I'm relatively new to powershell, far more comfortable with SQL.

I need to get some data out of the event logs. I've managed to establish so far that I need to use Get-WinEvent and use the xml element to get the actual info I want.

So far I've got:

```
$filterxml = "


            *[System[(EventID='4624')]]
            and
            (
            *[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] and (Data='10')]]
            or
            *[EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] and (Data='2')]]
            )


"
$Events = Get-WinEvent -maxEvents 1 -Filterxml $filterXml
# Get out the event message data            
ForEach ($Event in $Events) {            
    # Convert the event to XML            
    $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml() 

 #Now what?? I need to find out how to return the actual data in a form I 
#can put into a datatable.

}
```

It seems like it should be so easy to chuck out the values to either into variables or straight into a datatable etc.

I've been looking for a solution for a while without any luck.

Comment: Found a helpful post with relevant answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/303967/working-with-event-logs-in-powershell

Comment: "... and use the xml element to get the actual info I want." - What _do_ you want?

Comment: I doubt you really want to turn the object into XML in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Get-EventLog`:

```
$eventsIncludingTheId = Get-EventLog -LogName Application | ? { $_.EventID -eq 4624} 
# Export data as XML
$eventsIncludingTheId | Export-Clixml C:\temp\export.xml
# Reimport data from XML
$events = Import-Clixml C:\temp\export.xml
```

`Get-EventLog` offers you the different eventlog sections (application, system, ...) via `-LogName`.

If you want to know what properties `Get-Eventlog`delivers you can do:

```
 Get-EventLog -LogName Application | select -first 1 | gm
```

which will show you all properties that you can use in the `Where-Object` clause (`? { $_.EventID -eq 1234`)

Hope that helps